# Is my income Halal even if my skills were learned from a pirated source?

Tags: halal-haram

I'm student and from a middle class family. Most of the time  I don't have money. Everyone knows how much struggle a middle class family boy have to do.
So I share my problem's with my friends.

One of my friend give a paid course which he download from torrent site. I didn't know much about torrent , so I learn that skill and now I'm able earn money from that skill .

That particular skill name ui ux. Now I want to start job or freelancing with this skill.

I know downloading course from torrent is Haram
But my question is :

"From now if I work hard legally from that skill, my income halal or haram?"

Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Your income is halal if the work you do is halal, irrespective of how you learnt your skill.

Comment: I'd suggest you pay for the course after you earn money using the skill you acquired from the course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your income is inshallah allah halal and the work you do is also halal because you didnt know that the course was pirated but i would recommend you to just find the course online and pay for it so the creator would get what is his right.

Comment: Abdulrahman Sakah brother assalamualaikum
I want to know more details about my question